# PayPal Sandbox returning Internal Service Error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use the PayPal Sandbox for testing automated credit card processing, but running into an issue. When I charge in the amount of **$105** I get an `INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR` with a debug id of `de753957a889d`. If I go back and change the amount to something else like **$115** for instance, the charge goes through as expected. I have tried several different amounts and **$105** seems to be the only one that give me an error.

Here are the lines from the log file:

```
2013-08-27 12:45:36,570 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] grant_type=client_credentials

2013-08-27 12:45:37,376 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] Service response

2013-08-27 12:45:37,376 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] {"scope":"htts://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* htts://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card htts://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.* openid","access_token":"BJ7.168BhK3u0EgZ.MQgUABpdnTropRiXdCQ7ALrBHg","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-80W284485P519543T","expires_in":28800}

2013-08-27 12:45:37,698 [10] DEBUG PayPal.PayPalResource [(null)] Content-Type:application/json

2013-08-27 12:45:37,698 [10] DEBUG PayPal.PayPalResource [(null)] Authorization:Bearer BJ7.168BhK3u0EgZ.MQgUABpdnTropRiXdCQ7ALrBHg

2013-08-27 12:45:37,698 [10] DEBUG PayPal.PayPalResource [(null)] User-Agent:PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-dotnet 0.7.3 ;lang=DOTNET;v=4.0.30319.1008;bit=64;os=Windows 7 6.1.7601.65536;

2013-08-27 12:45:37,698 [10] DEBUG PayPal.PayPalResource [(null)] PayPal-Request-Id:14504bda-98c3-4b14-90fd-083663e80bfd

2013-08-27 12:45:37,789 [10] DEBUG PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] {"intent":"sale","payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"credit_card":{"number":"4417119669820331","type":"visa","expire_month":3,"expire_year":2015,"cvv2":"123","first_name":"David","last_name":"Krejci","billing_address":{"line1":"300 Technology Square","city":"Cambridge","country_code":"US","postal_code":"02139","state":"MA"}}}]},"transactions":[{"amount":{"currency":"USD","total":"105","details":{"shipping":"0","subtotal":"105","tax":"0"}},"description":"B4M Reg"}]}

2013-08-27 12:45:42,975 [10] ERROR PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] Error Response: {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"htts://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"de753957a889d"}

2013-08-27 12:45:42,976 [10] INFO  PayPal.Manager.ConnectionManager [(null)] Got InternalServerError status code from server

2013-08-27 12:45:43,035 [10] ERROR PayPal.Exception.PayPalException [(null)] Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Stream was not readable.
PayPal.Exception.PayPalException: Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Stream was not readable. ---> System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)
   at PayPal.HttpConnection.Execute(String payLoad, HttpWebRequest httpRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have 'Negative testing' enabled on your sandbox account(s) by any chance?
https://developer.paypal.com / > Applications > Sandbox accounts > Find your account > Click 'Profile' > Settings.

Negative testing lets you test specific error conditions for our classic API's by triggering a specific error code by passing them as 'AMT' value.
For example, for API error code 12345, you would set `AMT=123.45`.
For your error scenario I see us returning API error code 10500 internally. Which makes me strongly suspect you've got 'Negative testing' turned on for one of your sandbox accounts.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Is this documented anywhere? I would be interested to know more about how it works.

Comment: To be more specific, is this feature documented anywhere. To know in the future what errors codes I could be testing.

Comment: There is some documentation for our classic API's (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/#errors), but this functionality isn't fully worked out yet for REST API's unfortunately.

Comment: @PayPal_Robert FWIW i'm having similar issues BUT (a) negative testing is OFF; (b) sometimes the code works, sometimes NOT ... this has me wondering whether the "sandbox" has issues of its own. the negative testing is only for the business a.k.a. facilitator account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same card details many times than you may get this issue.
Please use different card you will not get this type of issue.